# Paypal Future payment Agreement page not showing link to merchantprivacypolicy and useragreement in android

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

paypal agreement page,where privacy policy and user agreement should be clickable which going to open the browser based on the link provided.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - it was also noticed internally yesterday. We will fix this SDK issue.

Comment: @MattJacunski Please vote for the post

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in version 2.3.0 of the SDK.  See https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/releases.